# Catching image load/error in Ember View

Tags: events, ember.js, onload, onerror

Trying to catch the load and error events for an Image within an EmberJS View handlebars template. The only way I can get it hooked up is to catch the jQuery events in the didInsertElement view function. But this is not a very Ember way of doing things, I've tried to bind the event as you'd do with click events but no luck.

Here is a JSFiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/qCaA2/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most elegant I could come up with:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Je9L/5/

I would have preferred to do this, but it is not working, and I'm not sure why not:

http://jsfiddle.net/7JXhA/3/

If you look at the jQuery docs for the load event (http://api.jquery.com/load-event/), it seems that these events may not be able to be handled with delegation the way other DOM events can be. That may be the underlying issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Agreed, I'd expect the second fiddle to work and to be the ember way of doing it. Maybe I'll submit a github issue. And thanks for the reminder to remove the event listener on destroy!

Comment: Yeah, I suspect it may be a browser limitation

Comment: The second fiddle doesn't work because progress events don't bubble.   Ember customEvents can only capture events that bubble.  See the full list here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events